# How to calculate the time difference using a SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table named tblemptimelog with the following columns:

empid - INT
workdate - DATE
timein1 - TIME
timeout1 - TIME
timein2 - TIME
timeout2 - TIME

My query:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblemptimelog
 WHERE empid = 1111
 ORDER BY workdate";
```

The results displayed as follows:

```
|Emp ID | Date       | Time In  | Time Out | Time In  | Time Out
|1111   | 04-18-2020 | 08:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:10:05 | 17:00:00
|1111   | 04-19-2020 | 08:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 17:00:00
```

I want to display the time difference between timein1 and timeout1.

As well as the time difference between timein2 and timeout2 for as follows:

```
|Emp ID | Date       | Time In  | Time Out | Time In  | Time Out | Total Time
|1111   | 04-18-2020 | 08:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:10:05 | 17:00:00 | 07:49:55
|1111   | 04-19-2020 | 08:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 08:00:00
```

I also want to display the total time.
In this case, it would be 15:49:55

```
Total: 15:49:55
```

How do I achieve my set goal?

Comment: Start with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff and union to get total row.

Comment: There's chance, that TimeIn>TimeOut is over midnight? Timediff not problem, you may use `TIMEDIFF()` and then `SUM()` for GROUP BY EmpID.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your **first part**  you may use `timediff & addtime`

> I am wanting to display the time difference between timein1 and
> timeout1 and the time difference between timein2 and timeout2

```
select
    a.*,
TIMEDIFF(time_out_1, time_in_1) diff_time_1,
TIMEDIFF(time_out_2, time_in_2) diff_time_2,
ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF(time_out_1, time_in_1), TIMEDIFF(time_out_2, time_in_2)) diff_time_1_and_2
from
    ( 
    select  TIME('08:00:00') time_in_1, TIME('12:00:00') time_out_1, TIME('13:10:05') time_in_2, TIME('17:00:00') time_out_2
    union all  
    select  TIME('08:00:00') time_in_1, TIME('12:00:00') time_out_1, TIME('13:00:00') time_in_2, TIME('17:00:00') time_out_2
    ) as a
```

result

```
time_in_1|time_out_1|time_in_2|time_out_2|diff_time_1|diff_time_2|diff_time_1_and_2|
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----------|-----------|-----------------|
 08:00:00|  12:00:00| 13:10:05|  17:00:00|   04:00:00|   03:49:55|         07:49:55|
 08:00:00|  12:00:00| 13:00:00|  17:00:00|   04:00:00|   04:00:00|         08:00:00|
```

To answer your **second part** you may use `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time)))` to convert to seconds then sum, then return  to time

> Also, after the table, I want to display the total time. In this case
> it would be 15:49:55
>
> Total: 15:49:55

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(diff_time_1_and_2))) total_time  from ( 
select
    a.*,
TIMEDIFF(time_out_1, time_in_1) diff_time_1,
TIMEDIFF(time_out_2, time_in_2) diff_time_2,
ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF(time_out_1, time_in_1), TIMEDIFF(time_out_2, time_in_2)) diff_time_1_and_2
from
    ( 
    select  TIME('08:00:00') time_in_1, TIME('12:00:00') time_out_1, TIME('13:10:05') time_in_2, TIME('17:00:00') time_out_2
    union all  
    select  TIME('08:00:00') time_in_1, TIME('12:00:00') time_out_1, TIME('13:00:00') time_in_2, TIME('17:00:00') time_out_2
    ) as a
    ) as b
```

result

```
total_time|
----------|
  15:49:55|
```